# "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, syntax-error

I am developing a Chrome Extension which replaces the home tab. It has a search box which is *supposed* to search with the default search engine. However, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Context
chrome://newtab/

Stack Trace
bg.js:103 (anonymous function)
```

Here is the code (the 2nd one is not `CSS`, it is `manifest.json` and I have excluded parts that won't be needed):

```js
// ...
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  chrome.search.query(queryInfo: {
    text: 'a'
  }, callback: function);
});
// ...
```

```css
/* manifest.json */
{
  "name": "Simple New Tab",
  "options_ui": {
      "page": "options.html",
      "open_in_tab": true
    },
  "version": "1.2",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["storage", "downloads", "<all_urls>"],
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "NewTab.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- ... -->
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="query" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button id="searcher"><svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"><path class="path1" d="M848.471 928l-263.059-263.059c-48.941 36.706-110.118 55.059-177.412 55.059-171.294 0-312-140.706-312-312s140.706-312 312-312c171.294 0 312 140.706 312 312 0 67.294-24.471 128.471-55.059 177.412l263.059 263.059-79.529 79.529zM189.623 408.078c0 121.364 97.091 218.455 218.455 218.455s218.455-97.091 218.455-218.455c0-121.364-103.159-218.455-218.455-218.455-121.364 0-218.455 97.091-218.455 218.455z"></path></svg></button>
</form>
<!-- ... -->
```

Edit - Here is a link which may help:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/search/ (documentation)

Comment: I see the problem ... the syntax isn't literally `chrome.search.query(queryInfo: QueryInfo, callback: function)` ... it's `chrome.search.query(queryInfo, callback)` ... the documentation is telling you that `queryinfo` is a `QuiryInfo` object and `callback` is a `function`

Comment: @JaromandaX Still getting the same annoying error. Here's the modified line: `chrome.search.query({text: 'a'}, function);`

Comment: I changed it to `chrome.search.query({'a'}, function);` and now getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'`

Comment: you do realise `function` is a placeholder for an actual function? and it's not `{'a'}` ... it's `{text: 'a'}`  - you removed too much

Comment: Now it gives this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
`

Comment: now that you have the syntax cleaned up, it's a matter of getting the manifest right so that `chrome.search` is available ... your documentation link states that you need permission "search"

Comment: Thanks - it works but when I put `q.value` instead of "a" it gives `Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of search.query(search.QueryInfo queryInfo, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'queryInfo': Missing required property 'text'.` (q is `$('#query');`)

Comment: perhaps `$('#query')` doesn't have a `.value`

Comment: Thanks - I have found that it is `.val`